# Matsubara Green's function

Tags: condensed-matter, interactions, greens-functions

The RKKY coupling has the form of $\chi_{i,j}(r,r')= \frac{-2}{\pi} Im \int_{-\infty}^{\varepsilon_F} d\varepsilon \; Tr[\sigma_i G(r,r',\varepsilon) \sigma_j G(r',r,\varepsilon)]$. 
where i and j refer to x,y or z. $\sigma$ denotes the Pauli matrix and G presents retarded Green's function which can be obtained by taking the Fourier transformation of $G(k,\varepsilon)=[(\varepsilon+i\eta) \; I - H (k)]^{-1}$.

Is there anybody who knows how I can calculate the spin susceptibility, $\chi(r,r')$, by using Matsubara Green's function, $\mathscr{G}(k,i\omega)=[i\omega\; I - H (k)]^{-1}$?